# Сохранение данных - проверка выполнения запросов

Tags: php, mysql

Как лучше всего реализовывать проверку выполнения mysql запросов?

К примеру есть функция, в которую приходит большой массив, я этот массив разбираю и начинаю обрабатывать данные. Одна часть массива идет на один запрос, другая крутится в цикле, где так же выполняются запросы на сохранение данных и т.д... Т.е. получается, что делается запросов 5, а может и 10...
И вот как проверять то это все?

К примеру первые запросы удалось выполнить. А вот какой-то промежуточный не прошел. И получается, что часть сработала, а часть нет.

Чтобы было понятнее где с таким столкнулся...

Редактирование цен товаров в заказе мультиязычного и мультивалютного магазина...

Я получаю массив с новыми ценами и другими данными.

1. пересчет валюты заказа, товаров заказа. 3 запрос.
2. в зависимости от дополнительных
   данны, например именили способ
   оплаты, то пересохраняю и их. 1
   запрос.
3. пересчет итоговых сумм. 1 запрос
4. сохранение других данных товара. 1
   запрос.
5. ....

По частям эти данные редактировать никто не будет. все в месте сохраняется. Получается, что если где-то возникнет ошибка, то ее можно пропустить.

И как быть в таких ситуация? Если не прошел промежуточный запрос, то предыдущие уже выполнились и данные частично обновлены.

Создавать массив в который собирать неудачные запросы и выводить потом их после сохранения, типа: При сохранении данных произошли ошибки - бла. бла... ?

Comment: а можно поинтересоваться зачем нужно пересчитывать цены в валюты и пересчитывать итоги какие-то? какой-то сложный алгоритм пересчета цен идет, такой, что цены в разных валютах надо хранить?

Comment: Если изменили валюту заказа, то цены нужно переконвертировать же.
Итого - итоговые суммы, которые включают в себя и общую сумму и отдельно по доставке, оплате, скидки и т.д... Сложного ничего нет. Все банально.

Comment: это я к тому, что ваши вычисления не нужны в базе. их можно делать непосредственно при выводе данных. Псевдокод:

    select o.ware_id, price*$rate as usd_price 
    from order o 
      join pricelist p on o.ware_id = p.ware_id

и суммы тоже

    select sum(price*$rate)...

Множество запросов на update'ы и insert'ы при действиях пользователя - плохая идея.

Comment: В заказе у меня есть валюта, в которой был сделан заказ, есть суммы: у товаров, у параметров товаров, итоговые, доставка и т.д...
Все это отдельно и выводится отдельно. Т.е. вся нужная информация о товаре в одной таблице, включая названия товаров, вся информация о Итого в другой таблице и т.д... При изменении только одной валюты в заказе, мне нужно в каждой таблице сделать пересчет цен. Данные редактирует только админ.

Comment: да, да я как раз про это. нет нужды в такой структуре и в таком количестве запросов. тут вопрос проектирования базы, а не того, что некоторые запросы у вас не срабатывают, что тоже в общем-то странно.

Comment: Данные все на своих местах и являются не зависимыми от реальной базы товаров и других настроек. Иного варианта организации я не вижу совершенно. Как вы предлагаете хранить данные о товарах, итоговые суммы, данные параметров товаров и т.д...? Там очень большой объем данных с кучей разных цен, скидок, доставок, оплат...

Ошибок никаких нет. Вопрос задан вообще о проверке такого рода, когда выполняется несколько запросов. Пример с заказом - первое, что вспомнилось, где такое видел.

Answer (score 3):

`mysqli_affected_rows()` - Возвращает число строк, затронутых последним `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `REPLACE` или `DELETE` запросом.

Также можно "завернуть" пачку обновления в транзакцию, и если где-то ошибка - не делать `commit`.

Врятли так будет, что запросы в середине с ошибкой, а потом без ошибок (Только при большой загрузке сервера).

Ещё можно попробовать все запросы сначала сохранить в буфер, через '`;`' - и за раз выполнить. Для этого может понадобится много памяти и больше 64кб вроде нельзя запросы слать.

Comment: мне как бы просто нотис выводить, что мол такие-то данные не обновлены.
В целом, если запрос выполнился, то возвращается true, если нет, то false(или ошибка). Т.е. можно собирать запросы с ошибками в массив, а потом уже выводить уведомление. Такой вариант не очень говнокодный?)

Comment: Гораздо более прозрачный и православный вариант с оборачиванием всех этих запросов в одну транзакцию, и, как следствие, полным её откатом в случае ошибки хотя бы в одном из запросов. Ну и, по возможности запросы на изменение (update/insert/delete) делать bulk'овым, т.е. отдавать данные, которые нужно изменить пачкой, а не по одному набору на запрос

Comment: Почему так - не делать коммит? Правильно будет явно выполнить rollback